# SQL Server - Multiple updates / correcting data entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to cleanup some imported data.  Changing some entries to a proper code I use.  I have it working but is there a cleaner way than lists of update/sets?

```
update List
  SET    STCode = REPLACE(STCode, 'Georgia','GEO')
update List
  SET    STCode = REPLACE(STCode, 'Louisiana','LOU')
etc...
```

Comment: Create a table of translations, join it to your table to be updated, and you only need one update statement.

Comment: Beware of replacements that need to be done in a specific order, e.g. "West Virginia" should probably be handled prior to "Virginia" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided `STCode` stores at most one value to be replaced ( no stuff like 'Georgia and Louisiana') lookup table is the solution

```
  update List
  set  STCode = REPLACE(STCode, replacement.bad, replacement.good)
  from List l
  join (
      values 
         ('Georgia','GEO')
        ,('Louisiana','LOU')
      ) replacement(bad, good)
      on l.STCode like '%' + replacement.bad + '%'
      ;
```

Answer (score 1):

could be using a transalation table with union  and a join

```
  UPDATE T1
  SET T1.STCode = T2.code
  FROM List AS T1
  INNER JOIN (
      select 'Georgia' name ,'GEO' code
      union 
      select 'Louisiana','LOU'
  ) T2 on .T1.STCode = T2.name
```